# SQL SERVER Join 2 tables with COUNT(*)

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, join, inner-join

I need some help to join my tables, I used 2 tables

//table news

```
id_news|title|
1 |first..|
2 |second..|
```

//table comment

```
id_comment|content|id_news
1|Haha..|1
2|Hahe..|2
3|Hoho..|1
```

I need an output use `COUNT(*)` comments in id_news 1

like

```
id_news|title|total_comment|
1|first..|**2**|
```

so far my syntax like

```
SELECT
    news.id_news,
    COUNT(distinct comment.id_news)
FROM
    news 
    inner join comment ON (comment.id_news=news.id_news)
group by 
    news.id_news
```

Comment: Your syntax uses column names that are not in the table.  Please fix the code so it matches the definitions.

Comment: oh sorry, I've fixed my question

Comment: just group by the first column `news.id_news` (instead of the mysterious and irrelevant `news.id_berita`) and use simply `count(*)`

Comment: I've fixed my question at last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT news.id_news, COUNT(*)
FROM news INNER JOIN
     comment
     ON comment.id_news = news.id_news
GROUP BY news.id_news;
```

Note the following:

- The `select` clause uses the same column as the `group by`
- The `COUNT()` is not using a distinct.  In your formulation, it would always return `1`, regardless of the number of comments.
- If you want news items with no comments, you would use a `left outer join` and change the `count(*)` to `count(comment.id_news)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query you will get the data as you want :

```
SELECT
    news.id_news,news.title,
    (select count(*) from comment group_by id_news) as total_comment
FROM
    news 
    inner join comment ON comment.id_news=news.id_news
```